# Find the limit $L=\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^{n}\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)$

Tags: limits

Find the limit following:

$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^{n}\sin\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2+n}\right)$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you attempted it?

Comment: $(-1)^n \sin x = \sin(x - \pi n)$

Comment: @Zhoe: Yes, i tried do, but can't

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin{(x+k\pi)}=(-1)^k\sin{x}$$
so
$$(-1)^n\sin{\pi\sqrt{n^2+n}}=(-1)^n\sin{(\pi(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n)+n\pi)}=\sin{\dfrac{n\pi}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}}\to 1,n\to \infty$$

Comment: $L\neq 1$.
$(-1)^n\sin(\pi(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n)+n\pi)\neq (-1)^n\sin(\pi(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n))\neq \sin\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}$

Comment: $(-1)^n\cdot(-1)^n=?$

Comment: Result: Limit does not exist

Comment: @math110, nice approach. I've a query, the first equality is defined for integer $n,$ right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,Thank you, I  think this problem $n$ is integer,because in china book,Our rules
 in limit $n$ mean integer.

Comment: @math110: You try to use Toylor's expansion. And the other is a result of your result.

Comment: In Indian and USA books too, $n \to \infty$ is supposed to mean tending to $\infty$ through integer values unless otherwise stated. The limit is $1$ under this condition and does not exist otherwise because if $n$ is supposed to be a real number tending to $\infty$ then we can't define $(-1)^{n}$ in the real number system.