# Limit of $\sin(\pi \sqrt{4n^2+n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

We can notice that $\sqrt{4n^2 + n} = \sqrt{4n^2(1+ \frac{1}{4n})} = 2n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4n}}$. Therefore

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin (2n\pi \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{4n}}) \text{ will be an even number}$$

Because the square root becomes $1$ and we end up with an even number: $\sin(\text{even number})$

And sine of an even number is $0$. But apparently that is not the right answer.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1372176/394456

Comment: The reasoning is wrong because the linear part of $\sqrt{4n^2+n}$ is absorbed by the sine, and a constant term remains.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do not understand what you mean. What linear part? Thanks

Comment: Find the oblique asymptote of $\sqrt{4n^2+n}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider that

$$\sin(\pi\sqrt{4n^2+n})=\sin(\pi\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2\pi n)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{\sqrt{4n^2+n}+2n}\right)\to\sin\frac\pi4.$$

Comment: What about $n = \frac{-1 +\sqrt{1+16k^2}}{8}$ for all $ k \in \mathbb{N}$, for which we have that $sin( \pi \sqrt{4n^2 +n}) = \sin (\pi k) = 0$ ?

Comment: @Ahmad Is this $n$ you define an integer, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: why is the limit consider just the integer cases ? why not all of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Ahmad: the limit for reals doesn't exist and is just uninteresting.

Comment: Because, implicit in the question is the fact that $n$ is an integer. (First, notation-wise, $n$ is usually used to denote integers, and $x$ reals; second, because otherwise the OP's sentence about even numbers cannot be interpreted at all.) @Ahmad

Answer (score 5):

When $n\to\infty$, we have
$$
\sqrt{4n^2+n} = 2n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4n}}
= 2n\left(1+\frac{1}{8n} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)
= 2n + \frac{1}{4} + o(1) \tag{1}
$$
using the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ for $x$ around $0$. Recalling that $$\forall a,b,\qquad \sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b \tag{2}$$ we get
$$\begin{align*}
\sin(\pi\sqrt{4n^2+n}) &=\sin\left(2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{4} + o(1)\right) \\
&= \sin(2n\pi) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + o(1)\right)
+ \cos(2n\pi) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + o(1)\right) \\
&= 0 + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + o(1)\right) \\
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \sin\frac{\pi}{4} = \boxed{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
\end{align*}$$
using continuity of $\sin$ (as $\frac{\pi}{4} + o(1)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{\pi}{4}$).

Comment: To the downvoter: why? Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Welcome to the club of the victims of mysterious downvotes and +1.